# Google Maps Marker, on hover interact with page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the following code to add a Marker to an on page Google Map

```
  var myMarker4 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.53, -2.5), map: map, icon: '/_Content/images/light-pink-marker-map.png' });
```

Is there a way (call back?) for me to detect when the user has hovered over the marker so I can do something on the current page?

I have several markers, so I would need someway to uniquely identify each.

Comment: Check the events here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what you're looking for?

```
var myMarker4 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.53, -2.5), map: map, icon: '/_Content/images/light-pink-marker-map.png' });

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker4, 'mouseover', function() {
    doSomething...
});
```

By the way, here's the full list of events that a marker can handle:

- 'click'
- 'dblclick'
- 'mouseup'
- 'mousedown'
- 'mouseover'
- 'mouseout'